# To have online Repository for Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to create an Online SVN repository so that Once i commit a code on that repository i can Access it from anywhere through an Internet.Any help on this would be appreciated..

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to go about it.

### Use an online svn repository

[Here](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/subversion/) is a good comparison of online svn hosting sites.

One suggestion is
https://riouxsvn.com/

---

### Setup a repository on your hosting solution

1. [Creating it using svnadmin command line](http://civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps).
2. [Creating a repository with tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html).

Comment: @lakshman: Thanks for editing for the missing link. I have now updated my answer to reflect better information.